# Error while joing the TLS enabled peer to channel in Hyperledger

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I just up the hyperledger docker container. I use TLS enabled orderer and peers. I created the channel using the command in cli bash(for peer0)

```
peer channel create -o orderer0.Myname.com:7050 -c Mynamechannel -f /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/channel-artifacts/channel.tx --tls --cafile /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/ordererOrganizations/Myname.com/orderers/orderer0.Myname.com/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.Myname.com-cert.pem
```

It runs successfully. Then I try to join the channel using the command

```
export CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.Myname.com/users/Admin@org1.Myname.com/msp
export CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.org1.Myname.com:7051
export CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID="Org1Myname"
export CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.Myname.com/peers/peer0.org1.Myname.com/tls/ca.crt
peer channel join -b Mynamechannel.block
```

But got the errors some thing like

```
2019-02-07 05:53:15.047 UTC [msp/identity] Sign -> DEBU 006 Sign: digest: 143E4E155F1757BB9987562A28A4901B61615989BDB7B6ACD804FF60B2A15F0A 
2019-02-07 05:53:15.047 UTC [grpc] Printf -> DEBU 007 transport: http2Client.notifyError got notified that the client transport was broken read tcp 192.168.64.19:60288->192.168.64.18:7051: read: connection reset by peer.
2019-02-07 05:53:15.048 UTC [grpc] Printf -> DEBU 008 transport: http2Client.notifyError got notified that the client transport was broken unexpected EOF.
2019-02-07 05:53:15.049 UTC [grpc] Printf -> DEBU 009 transport: http2Client.notifyError got notified that the client transport was broken unexpected EOF.
2019-02-07 05:53:15.050 UTC [grpc] Printf -> DEBU 00a transport: http2Client.notifyError got notified that the client transport was broken read tcp 192.168.64.19:60294->192.168.64.18:7051: read: connection reset by peer.
Error: proposal failed (err: rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = transport: write tcp 192.168.64.19:60288->192.168.64.18:7051: use of closed network connection)
```

And sometimes get an another error that

```
019-02-07 07:06:38.322 UTC [msp/identity] Sign -> DEBU 005 Sign: digest: D43291FFCD0DE17F5CC33A7DBBB47D043FE83C91EA8514EDCED6AC1D31C0A061 
2019-02-07 07:06:38.322 UTC [grpc] Printf -> DEBU 006 transport: http2Client.notifyError got notified that the client transport was broken write tcp 192.168.80.19:56288->192.168.80.18:7051: write: connection reset by peer.
Error: proposal failed (err: rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = transport: write tcp 192.168.80.19:56288->192.168.80.18:7051: write: connection reset by peer)
```

Thanks in advance.

Fabric : 1.1.0

Os: Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: try adding `export CORE_PEER_TLS_ENABLED=true`

Comment: Done...This was solved my problem. Thanks @GariSingh